# How to translate and rotate in TikZ in foreach loop to animate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'd like to animate the horizontal segment to the vertical one, rotating it around its mid point and translating it. See the gif below.

I have no idea why the translation does not work as I expect. The purple segment should move to the final blue position.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {0,1,...,10}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-.2,-1.2) rectangle (4.2,2.2);
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,2);

\draw[red] (1,0) -- +(1,0);
\draw[blue] (2,1) -- +(0,1);

\draw[thick] (1,0)++(\a/10,\a/10) -- +(1,0); % translation

\draw[thick] let \p1=(1,0), \p2=(2,0) in [rotate around={-9*\a:(1.5,0)}] (\p1) -- (\p2) ; % rotation around mid point

\draw[thick,red!50!blue,shift={+(\a/10,\a/10)}] let \p1=(1,0), \p2=(2,0) in [rotate around={-9*\a:(1.5,0)}] (\p1) -- (\p2) ; % rotation + translation WRONG!!

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {0,1,...,10}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-.2,-1.2) rectangle (4.2,2.2);
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,2);

\draw[red] (1,0) -- +(1,0);
\draw[blue] (2,1) -- +(0,1);

%\draw[thick] (1,0)++(\a/10,\a/10) -- +(1,0); % translation

%\draw[thick,green!20!black] let \p1=(1,0), \p2=(2,0) in [rotate around={-9*\a:(1.5,0)}] (\p1) -- (\p2) ; % rotation around mid point

\draw[thick,red!50!blue,shift={(\a/20,\a*1.5/10)}
] 
    let \p1=(1,0), 
        \p2=(2,0) in 
    [rotate around={-9*\a:(1.5,0)}] 
    (\p1) -- (\p2) ; % rotation + translation WRONG!!

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly. So the trick is to change the `shift`.

Comment: If `\a=10` the `xshift` should be one half and `yshift` should be one and a half. Interesting! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, at most `a=10` and as the middle is positioned relative to its starting point at `(0.5,1.5)`. Just divide by `20`  the abscissae since `10/20=0.5` and to multiply the ordinates by `1.5` since `10x1.5/10=1.5`.

Comment: I'll try to insert some variables in case I decide to use more frames. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the line:

```
\draw [green,rotate around={-9*\a:(2,0.1*\a)}] (1,0.1*\a) -- (2,0.1*\a); %Correct rotation
```

So it would look like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {0,1,...,10}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-.2,-1.2) rectangle (4.2,2.2);
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,2);

\draw[red] (1,0) -- +(1,0);
\draw[blue] (2,1) -- +(0,1);

\draw[thick] (1,0)++(\a/10,\a/10) -- +(1,0); % translation

\draw[thick] let \p1=(1,0), \p2=(2,0) in [rotate around={-9*\a:(1.5,0)}] (\p1) -- (\p2) ; % rotation around mid point

\draw[thick,red!50!blue,shift={+(\a/10,\a/10)}] let \p1=(1,0), \p2=(2,0) in [rotate around={-9*\a:(1.5,0)}] (\p1) -- (\p2) ; % rotation + translation WRONG!!

%\draw [magenta,rotate around={-9*\a:(2,0)}] (1,0) -- (2,0); %rotation

%\draw [yellow] (1,0.1*\a) -- (2,0.1*\a);%translation vertical

\draw [green,rotate around={-9*\a:(2,0.1*\a)}] (1,0.1*\a) -- (2,0.1*\a); %Correct rotation

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```